# Zend_View Rendered with no PHP Code executed

Tags: zend-framework, xampp

When rendering a Zend_View, the php code inside it is not executed and I get back the actual text of the view. 
Example:

```
<?echo 'Hello';?>
```

I would expect the output to be

```
Hello
```

instead I get back

```
<?echo 'Hello';?>
```

**Configuration**:
xampp 1.7.3 (php 5.3.1) on Windows 7, Zend Framework 1.10.4

**NOTE:**
 I **DO** have this issue
 1. when running php from command line
 2. when running phpunit through netbeans

I **DON'T** have this issue
 1. when running php through Apache
 2. when running phpunit from command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at short tag configuration in the php ini you use in those situations and also see if processing .phtml is set up

to get the ini you are using on command line use php --ini

Comment: In php.ini, switch short_open_tag to "On" and its all good! thanks!

Comment: If you're going to use short tags, you might as well use the shortcut `echo` too, ie `<?= 'Hello' ?>`

Comment: For the record, Zend Framework is moving away from recommending short-tag usage. (due to reasons like this, it doesn't always work out of the box)